# Electrical components failing in a Poisson process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

A machine has infinitely many identical components. They fail according to a Poisson process with rate $\lambda = 4$/hour. A repairman arrives at time $t$ and instantly repairs all of the broken components, but components cost more to fix the longer they have been broken. The cost to repair a component is $\$10$/hour it has been down.

Suppose that all components are functional at time $0$. What is the expected cost of the repairs at time $t$ hours?

(Example for clarification: if one component fails at time $t=3.5$ and another at time $t=4$, and the repairman arrives at time $t=5$, then the total cost would be $15+10=25$.)

My thinking for this problem so far is as follows. The expected number of failures is $λt=4t$. The expected mean downtime for these broken components should be $t/2$. Thus, the expected cost of repairs is the product $(4t)(t/2)(10 \text{ per hour})$, or $20(t^2)$. Is this line of reasoning correct? Thanks.

Comment: You are making some implicit assumptions to get your result (such as: given a component has failed by time $t$, its time of failure is uniform in $[0,t]$) and as far as I can see, those assumptions are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is sound for a Homogeneous Poisson Process.

1. over time $\tau$, there will be $\lambda\tau$ failures,
2. From the [definition of the Poisson Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process#Definition), the occurrences are distributed uniformly on any interval of time, giving the expected arrival time of all of them in the middle of the interval.